# Formatting a laptop hard drive (PS3 drive) to FAT32

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, formatting, fat32

My PS3 broke down and i am trying to fix it, hopefully this can be done by formatting and reinstalling the OS on its HDD.

The HDD is a standard laptop 2.5" drive.

I have tried swapping it with my laptop's HDD, running the Windows 7 install DVD and running a bunch of commands from a command line:

> diskpart list
>
> select disk 0
>
> create partition primary
>
> format E: /FS:FAT32

This fails with an error that the volume is too large (120GB) to be formatted with FAT32.

How can i format this drive to FAT32? (PS3 forums suggest this is the right way in order to properly restore the OS later on).

Note that i don't have access to an actual machine running operating system UI (since i have room for only 1 drive in the laptop).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the flag `/A:8192` to the format line, to increase the allocation unit size

[Formatting FAT32 partition on 500GB HDD](https://superuser.com/questions/276743/formatting-fat32-partition-on-500gb-hdd)

If that doesn't work, I'd recommend getting hold of, or creating, a live USB bootable version of some flavour of linux, and formatting the drive with that `mkfs -t vfat /dev/hda1'

Answer (score 0):

Format it as NTFS first, then reformat it with [fat32format](http://www.ridgecrop.demon.co.uk/index.htm?fat32format.htm) - the second formatting is VERY fast, and the first format is primarily so that the drive will get a letter - if there's a drive letter already you can skip this step

[Windows XP and newer does *not* support formatting drives larger than 32 gb](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;Q314463&) by design so a third party tool is needed to do this