# How to create a large FAT32 partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, fat32

It is a 640GB hard drive. The FAT32 partition needs to be at least 120GB. I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: If you need the partition to be shared with a dualboot Windows installation, I suggest you to use a NTFS filesystem rather than a FAT32.

Comment: FAT32 does not support partitions that size. Even if you manage to make a partition larger then the specification, what happens when Windows and/or Linux read the partition, cannot be determined.  There is always exFAT which Windows 7 fully supports.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting FAT32 partition on 500GB HDD](https://superuser.com/questions/276743/formatting-fat32-partition-on-500gb-hdd)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

install gparted and use the GUI interface.

Comment: The program did its job however this did not fix what i need but thank you.